# A bound for the generalized Variational Distance

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Define,
$$
V(\alpha ,P,Q)=\sum _{i}|\alpha p_{i} -(1-\alpha )q_{i} |
$$

where $P=(p_{1} ,...,p_{n})$ and $Q=(q_{1} ,...,q_{n} )$ are two discrete distributions, and $0<\alpha<1$ is a class prior.

From some theoretical considerations I believe that $V(\alpha ,P,Q)\ge|2\alpha-1|$, but how do I prove it?

Comment: Triangular inequality makes this direct.

Comment: @Did, this distance does not obey the triangle inequality (unless for equal priors).

Comment: Again: $\sum|x_i|\geqslant\left|\sum x_i\right|$. Try $x_i=\alpha p_i-(1-\alpha)q_i$.

Comment: @Did, thanks much!